How to force close a channel at the original state, for a good cause
A few months ago I created a payment channel from my desktop node, on LND, to my mobile node, on Blixt. Then I tested a few payments between the nodes, and the final balance on the mobile phone is now about 20K sats (not that much). Unfortunately, I crashed my mobile phone, and now I am unable to perform a cooperative close of the payment channel. I do not have a backup of the Blixt wallet, because was used only for testing. I think the only option I have to recover the funds on the mobile node would be to perform a force close of the channel using its original state, when the Blixt node balance was zero. I know for sure that the mobile node won't be able to react and to broadcast a punishment transaction, because it is crashed, so I will be able to "steal" the 20K sats from my own mobile wallet. Unfortunately, I have no idea about how to do this technically.
Can someone help?

Just be sure that the channel wasn’t signed up with a watchtower, otherwise you might lose the other side of the channel as well
